# why does this parent element choose other elements too?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have 4 boxes of div tags, which each one has different divs inside.  By jQuery I want to make the second child of the clicked div highlighted or change its color. Also each parent div has a hidden div inside that after click on the parent div, the child div shows.
I made something similar to what I want but after clicking on the a div, it does the operation on other parent div too. Have a look at the demo to see what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/e3TeY/

And here is my JS code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".close").hide();
    $("div").click(function(){
        var classname = $(this).parent();
        alert(classname);
        $(classname).children(':first-child').next().css("color","white");
        $(classname).find(".close").show();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="item1">
    <div class="name1">name 1</div>
    <div class="name2">name 2</div>
    <div class="name3">name 3</div>
    <div class="close">close</div>
</div>
<div class="item2">
    <div class="name4">name 1</div>
    <div class="name5">name 2</div>
    <div class="name6">name 3</div>
    <div class="close">close</div>
</div>
<div class="item3">
    <div class="name7">name 1</div>
    <div class="name8">name 2</div>
    <div class="name9">name 3</div>
    <div class="close">close</div>
</div>
<div class="item4">
    <div class="name10">name 1</div>
    <div class="name11">name 2</div>
    <div class="name12">name 3</div>
    <div class="close">close</div>
</div>
```

So do you have any idea to make it like only do the operation on selected parent div (change color of its second child and show its hidden div child) ?

Comment: I'd change the structure. What's there isn't helpful. Put a common class on the parent divs if you want to work with them as a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a clean solution. Better define a common className for parent divs `item`

```
<div class="item item1">
    <div class="name1">name 1</div>
    <div class="name2">name 2</div>
    <div class="name3">name 3</div>
    <div class="close">close</div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".close").hide();
    $("div.item > div").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find("div:nth-child(2)").css("color","white");
        $(this).parent().find(".close").show();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ergec/2PjbP/

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but the problem is it only works when u actually click on the second child. But I want it operates when I click on any of the divs inside parents divs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of target all the `div`:

```
$("div").click(function(){
```

You can use attribute **[starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** `^*` instead to target expected `div` with class `name`:

```
$("div[class^=name]").click(function(){
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3TeY/1/)**

Comment: Using `^=` with `class` is very fragile.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, but I'm not sure any other better way based on his current HTML markup though.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Seems working. and great. @T.J.Crowder I don't know what you mean by fragile in this case as I am new in jQuery. However I prefer using a common id for same div and it sounds more trust able to use.

Comment: @user3229902: The class attribute contains a *list* of classes, with spaces between them. If you use `div[class^=name]`, it look look for divs whose class attribute *starts with* name. So it'll match `<div class="name1 foo">` but not `<div class="foo name1">` even though from all other standpoints, those are the same thing. So adding a class later (which is normal) will break this, which is why it's fragile.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of using jQuery's `toggleClass()` method for these situations.

You would have to edit the HTML and CSS a bit,
but with this method you can toggle the 'white & close' on / off.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/e3TeY/6/

**HTML**

```
<div class="item1 box">  
    <div class="name1">name 1</div>  
    <div class="name2 color">name 2</div>  
    <div class="name3">name 3</div>  
    <div class="close hidden">close</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.white {color:white;}
.hidden {display:none;}
.yes {display:block;}
```

**jQuery** *(alert removed)*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".box").click(function(){
  var classname = $(this).parent();         
  $(this).find("div:nth-child(2)").toggleClass('white');            
  $(this).find("div:nth-child(4)").toggleClass('yes');
 });
});
```